# ImportError on scipy.misc.imrotate

Tags: scipy

I'm in the midst of trying to create my own radon transform function, for which I need to rotate the simple image I've created. According to the documentation, the function is in scipy.misc.

However,

```
from scipy.misc import imrotate
```

gives me "could not import name imrotate"

and

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imrotate(myImage,theta)
```

says that scipy.misc does not have a module named 'imrotate' when I try to call the function.

I've tried removing the '--pylab inline' arguments from my launch, and I've made sure the PIL/Image libraries aren't imported, because I've heard that there were problems with that in other threads, but nothing seems to make it work.

I've gotten around it for now by using a different suite, the scikit-image library, but I'd prefer to use the scipy version if I can, because it's more commonly used.

Comment: Does `import PIL` work for you?  This function depends on `PIL`.

Comment: Tried adding `import PIL` before the scipy.misc import, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: is the behavior any different in IPython from a plain `python` terminal prompt?

Comment: Nope, I get the same two errors when I try it fron the Ipython terminal and other terminals such as IDLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imrotate` requires the library PIL and I guess that is your problem. Ether it is not installed at all or not installed correctly.

You can use `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate` instead.

Comment: Excellent. `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate` does just what I need. I guess PIL isn't installed afterall, though it didn't give me any warnings when I tried to import it. Thank you for the reply.